# why doesn't GRUB respond to my keyboard

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, keyboard

I recently bought an HP Pavilion TP01-2019 Desktop Computer with Windows 11 pre-installed.
It ran fine, and MUCH faster than my circa 2005 Pavilion a1210n, running dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.
I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 and set it up for dual boot.
The install went as expected and boot-up showed the GRUB menu screen with both Ubuntu and Windows options, and Ubuntu loaded and ran fine.
I could see/open the Windows filesystem from within the Ubuntu file manager, so that's all good.
Unfortunately, when it came time to actually test if Windows still worked, GRUB didn't respond to my keyboard inputs so I wasn't able to select the Windows option. It simply timed out and happily booted into Ubuntu again.
I've looked through the system's BIOS/UEFI settings, but there doesn't appear to be anything there that will address this problem.
Any ideas as to how to proceed will be appreciated.

Additional Info Added 18-OCT-22: When I first fired up the new PC out of the box, I wanted to use the keyboard from my older PC because it is of superior construction, however the new PC stated that the old keyboard was incompatible, so I was forced to use the new keyboard that came with the new PC. I don't know if this new info is significant or not, but it might be of some help.

Comment: Check the BIOS and see if the keyboard can be set into Legacy mode.  Also, you might want to try power resetting the system by removing all power from it, then press the power button a few times.  Then plug the power back in and power it back on.  If the battery cannot be removed, unplug the power, then power off the system and then press and hold the power button for 30 seconds.  Then power it back on.

Comment: Grub runs before any OS has been booted, and its very dependent on what the *firmware* on the device you're using was designed to use; for some models the OEM/maker used the firmware from a different/earlier device & omitted changing everything meaning it can be problematic/limited without *firmware* upgrade (*if available*)

Comment: To Terrance: there are no setting available in the BIOS/UEFI that pertain to "Legacy" or keyboard.

Comment: To Guiverc: The keyboard worked with Windows 11 before the Ubuntu install, and it works with Ubuntu after the install. In fact, I'm using it now. It even works to interrupt the POST so that I can check/edit the BIOS/UEFI settings. It just doesn't work within the GRUB menu. I doubt that there is a firmware upgrade available, but I'll check into that.

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks, I swapped my new keyboard for an older one that was known to be compatible with my system, but that didn't solve the problem. So, when plugging my new keyboard back in, I decided to swap USB ports with the mouse (ie. plug the keyboard in where the mouse was and plug mouse in where the keyboard was). Couldn't hurt!

Well, coincidence or not, the GRUB cursor now responds to my arrow keys.

:)

I don't know if it was the older keyboard that tweaked some setting, or swapping USB ports, but I'm just glad it's now working as it should.

Thanks to those who offered their assistance.